# CSS Grid with table like layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm having a problem with making `<ul>` and `<ol>` to behave properly when text line breaks within.

I saw some answer here on stackoverflow that you could set `display: table` on the ul/ol, `table-row` on the li and `table-cell` on the li::before element. That works like I want but limits me so I can't set a `margin-bottom` on the li.

Setting `text-indent` and negative `margin` wont work either because the width of the ::before element will differ. E.g if the counter goes to double digits instead of single.

So my question is if it's possible to solve this using the new grid layout? Been tinkering a bit but I haven't been able to keep all the ::before elements the same width without setting a fixed width.

Anyone got any ideas how to solve this?

**Edit:**
The content is generated from a CMS so I'm limited with using their markup. Which is a regular ul/ol with li tags.

**Update**

I want the text to align like this which my current code handles well with unordered lists
[image]

But when handling ordered lists it gets more complicated because the `::before` element that is my bullet and number can differ in with. Eg

[image]

Single digits handle okay but when going double digits the number will eventually overflow the text. So I want all the `::before` element to have the same width, so the text still aligns correctly. In this case the width should be equal to the largest `::before` element (number 10)

Example code

```
ol {
  counter-reset: list;

  & li {
    position: relative;
    counter-increment: list;
    padding-left: 18px;

    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin-right: 8px;
      content: counter(list);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use inner divs to set margins, so your li elements have display: table-cell put inside inner divs and set margins to them. Or if you will not need borders you can use transparent border instead of margins

Comment: @JavaEvgen Can't do that because I don't have control over the markup. Added comment about that in my question

Comment: what about transparent border then? btw downvote isn't mine

Comment: @JavaEvgen That didn't work either :/ I'll maybe have to revert back to using a fixed width for the ::before element

Comment: Could post the code or a screenshot of your problem? What exatcly is the "problem" you're having with line breaks?

Comment: @flen I've added a more detailed example now

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but you made the position of the `::before` pseudo-element absolute, that's why it overflows and stays put where you placed it. Why did you make the position absolute? If I understood your intention correctly, you want the `<li>`s to remain in the same column width, but you also want that, as the counter increases its digits, the counter moves to the left. If so, it can't be positioned absolute, I think, otherwise it won't ever move left

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? If so, you need to transfer to LESS since that doesn't run very well here.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: list;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    counter-increment: list;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
li:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: -1.5em;
      margin-right: 8px;
      content: counter(list);
      width: 2em;
      text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
<li>Lorem</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis condimentum massa.</li>
</ol>
```